# Detect round number in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I find out whether a float in PHP is a round number?

```
is_round(1.5); // false
is_round(1.0); // true
is_round(1.00000001); // false
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modification to Rob's code regarding sterofrog's comment. Code checks to ensure the value is also numeric.

```
function is_round($value) {
    return is_numeric($value) && intval($value) == $value;
}
```

Comment: If you're checking whether a number is round, you should already have verified that a variable is actually a number. `is_round('bar') => false` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 6):

```
function is_round( $value ) {
    return intval( $value ) == $value;
}
```

Comment: **@stereofrog:** How come? `intval('bar') != 'bar'` since `0 != 'bar'`.

Answer (score 2):

A much shorter version: `!fmod($num,1)` in PHP or this in JS: `!($num % 1)`

As a (more readable) function:

```
function is_round( $num ) {
  return !fmod($num, 1);
}
```

This works on the basis that any number that's not exactly 0 is falsey. You can use `fmod($num,1)` to get the decimals of a number; once you have those you can just `!` them.

Answer (score -1):

The function specified on [this page](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) by thierryreeuwijk should specify your needs.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, because the incoming variable is still a `float`. Or am I mistaken and this will work?

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($value = round($value))
```

Should work.