# Percentage display issue

Tags: php, formatting

i have a value that i calculate between 0 -100 ,
its usually a float number like 5.87876 , so i use **number_format** like :

```
$format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

the problem is , even the calculate number is integer like : `100`

its show `100.00`

but i want to display it like : 100

what is the elegant way to achive this ?

(i mean without else if ..)

Comment: I don't think there is a way without checking `$number`, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the *shortest* way I know.

```
$digits =        (is_numeric($number) && intval($number) == $number ? 0 : 2);
$format_number = number_format($number, $digits, '.', '');
```

The `is_numeric` and `intval` trick is taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349139/detect-round-number-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

so you are trying to have an accuracy of two decimal places after the dot, but suppress the .00 on integers?  I'd use sprintf:

```
$numbers = Array(3.141, 5.87876, 10.9999, 100);


foreach( $numbers as $n ) {
    $string = sprintf("%6.2f\n", $n);
    $string = str_replace(".00", "   ", $string);
    echo $string;
}
```

The output is

```
  3.14
  5.88
 11   
100
```